# SecurityException while connecting to CRM from Host Machine (The token provider cannot get tokens..... )

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to retrieve the data from CRM(that is on virtual machine) using WCF Service(that is on Host computer). 
I am running into the below SecurityException intermittently at **Service.RetrieveMultiple** while I am debugging from Host and trying to connect to CRM.

**Code:**

```
QueryExpression queryIssue = new QueryExpression
```

{
EntityName = irpc_Issue.EntityLogicalName,
ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new String[] { "irpc_issueid", "irpc_issuename"}),
Criteria = new FilterExpression()
};

queryIssue.Criteria.AddCondition("irpc_issueid", ConditionOperator.Equal, issueGuid);
data.Issue = new NameGuid();
data.Issue.Name = service.RetrieveMultiple(queryIssue).Entities.FirstOrDefault().Attributes["irpc_issuename"].ToString();

**Exception Details:**

System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: {"The token provider cannot get tokens for target 'http://irpc-dc/amgen/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc'."}

InnerException: {"The NetworkCredentials provided were unable to create a Kerberos credential, see inner exception for details."}
Source: mscorlib

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityProtocol.GetToken(SecurityTokenProvider provider, EndpointAddress target, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.GetTokenAndEnsureOutgoingIdentity(SecurityTokenProvider provider, Boolean isEncryptionOn, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityTokenAuthenticator authenticator)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.TryGetTokenSynchronouslyForOutgoingSecurity(Message message, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, Boolean isBlockingCall, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityToken& token, SecurityTokenParameters& tokenParameters, SecurityToken& prerequisiteWrappingToken, IList`1& supportingTokens, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState& newCorrelationState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.SecureOutgoingMessageCore(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.SecureOutgoingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase query)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.RetrieveMultipleCore(QueryBase query)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase query)

I have run the SETSPN command on Guest (SETSPN -A HTTP/irpc-dc IRPC\CrmService ) by referring to the thread here 
http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crm2011beta/thread/132a6d26-04fc-4e1e-8a7e-06088e106578

Still I am running into this Exception.

I am wondering if anybody are running into the same error.

Any help/ suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you say "intermittently", that means there are also occasions where it works ?

Is this with the CRM 2011 Beta ? The Beta introduced authentication issues that weren't present in the CTP 4. Have you recently run Windows/Microsoft Update on the VM ? The Beta received an update through WU earlier this month. I don't know whether they did anything about the authentication issues (at least I haven't read anything on that), but it'd be worth a try in case you haven't updated yet.

Comment: Yes. there are cases where it worked and i did Windows update as well. Still having authentication issues from Host to Guest.